# how to pass the data from child component to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-component

now I am trying to send the data from child component to parent.

I have researched lot i didnt get any good solution. if there is a solution can any explain me to solve this.

**APP.js**

```
 import React from 'react';
    import IntegrationDownshift from './members'
    class App extends React.Component {
         constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
             Name: "Name from state...",
             Description: "Description from state...",
            Data:[data]
          }
       }
      render() {  
         return (
            <div>
     <IntegrationDownshift Members={this.state.Data}/>
           </div>
         );
      }
    }

export default App;`
```

**members**

```
var suggestions = []
var members=[];
function renderInput(inputProps) {
  const { InputProps, classes, ref, ...other } = inputProps;
  return (
    <TextField
      InputProps={{
        inputRef: ref,
        classes: {
          root: classes.inputRoot,
          input: classes.inputInput,
        },
        ...InputProps,
      }}
      {...other}
    />
  );
}
function renderSuggestion(suggestionProps) {
  const { suggestion, index, itemProps, highlightedIndex, selectedItem } = suggestionProps;
  const isHighlighted = highlightedIndex === index;
  const isSelected = (selectedItem || '').indexOf(suggestion.label) > -1;
  return (
    <MenuItem
      {...itemProps}
      key={suggestion.label}
      selected={isHighlighted}
      component="div"
      style={{
        fontWeight: isSelected ? 500 : 400,
      }}
    >
      {suggestion.label}
    </MenuItem>
  );
}
renderSuggestion.propTypes = {
  highlightedIndex: PropTypes.number,
  index: PropTypes.number,
  itemProps: PropTypes.object,
  selectedItem: PropTypes.string,
  suggestion: PropTypes.shape({ label: PropTypes.string }).isRequired,
};
function getSuggestions(value, { showEmpty = false } = {}) {
  const inputValue = deburr(value.trim()).toLowerCase();
  const inputLength = inputValue.length;
  let count = 0;
  return inputLength === 0 && !showEmpty
    ? []
    : suggestions.filter(suggestion => {
        const keep =
          count < 5 && suggestion.label.slice(0, inputLength).toLowerCase() === inputValue;
        if (keep) {
          count += 1;
        }
        return keep;
      });
}
function DownshiftMultiple(props) {
    suggestions=props.Members;
  const { classes } = props;
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = React.useState([]);
  function handleKeyDown(event) {
    if (selectedItem.length && !inputValue.length && event.key === 'Backspace') {
      setSelectedItem(selectedItem.slice(0, selectedItem.length - 1));
    }
  }
  function handleInputChange(event) {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  }
  function handleChange(item) {
    let newSelectedItem = [...selectedItem];
    if (newSelectedItem.indexOf(item) === -1) {
      newSelectedItem = [...newSelectedItem, item];
      members=newSelectedItem;   // **want to send this**
       props.onDataChanged(members)// **here i'm trying to send the value**
    }
    setInputValue('');
    setSelectedItem(newSelectedItem);
  }    
  const handleDelete = item => () => {
    const newSelectedItem = [...selectedItem];
    newSelectedItem.splice(newSelectedItem.indexOf(item), 1);
    setSelectedItem(newSelectedItem);
  };    
  return (
    <Downshift
      id="downshift-multiple"
      inputValue={inputValue}
      onChange={handleChange}
      selectedItem={selectedItem}
    >
      {({
        getInputProps,
        getItemProps,
        getLabelProps,
        isOpen,
        inputValue: inputValue2,
        selectedItem: selectedItem2,
        highlightedIndex,
      }) => {
        const { onBlur, onChange, onFocus, ...inputProps } = getInputProps({
          onKeyDown: handleKeyDown,
          placeholder: 'Select multiple Members',
        });

        return (
          <div className={classes.container}>
            {renderInput({
              fullWidth: true,
              classes,
              InputLabelProps: getLabelProps(),
              InputProps: {
                startAdornment: selectedItem.map(item => (
                  <Chip
                    key={item}
                    tabIndex={-1}
                    label={item}
                    className={classes.chip}
                    onDelete={handleDelete(item)}
                  />
                )),
                onBlur,
                onChange: event => {
                  handleInputChange(event);
                  onChange(event);
                },
                onFocus,
              },
              inputProps,
            })}

            {isOpen ? (
              <Paper className={classes.paper} square>
                {getSuggestions(inputValue2).map((suggestion, index) =>
                  renderSuggestion({
                    suggestion,
                    index,
                    itemProps: getItemProps({ item: suggestion.label }),
                    highlightedIndex,
                    selectedItem: selectedItem2,
                  }),
                )}
              </Paper>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        );
      }}
    </Downshift>
  );
}

DownshiftMultiple.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    height: 250,
  },
  container: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    position: 'relative',
  },
  paper: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 1,
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
  chip: {
    margin: theme.spacing(0.5, 0.25),
  },
  inputRoot: {
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  inputInput: {
    width: 'auto',
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  divider: {
    height: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));

let popperNode;

export default function IntegrationDownshift(props) {
    debugger
  const classes = useStyles();
  const Members=props.Members;
   props.onDataChanged("test")

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>

      <DownshiftMultiple classes={classes} Members={Members}  />

    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm trying to implement this https://codesandbox.io/s/runh6 functionality which is material UI. I'm able to send the value from parent to child. but its not coming back to parent.

Now I want to read the **members** value in app.js. Is there a way to read the data in app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parent function to childred by using `props`.

That means that you can call parent function in child component.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import IntegrationDownshift from './members'
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
        Name: "Name from state...",
        Description: "Description from state...",
        Data:[] // init Data as empty
     }
  }
  addNewSelectedItem = (newItem) => {
    // you can add new Item from a child.
    this.setState(prevState => ({ Data: [...prevState.Data, newItem] }));
  }
  render() {  
     return (
        <div>
           <IntegrationDownshift addNewSelectedItem={this.addNewSelectedItem} Members={this.state.Data}/>
        </div>
     );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**IntegrationDownshift** Component

```
function DownshiftMultiple(props) {
...
handleChange(item) {
  //some operations
  props.addNewSelectedItem(item); // call parent function which is received by props.
}
...
```

Comment: here you can able to see my code in HTML section https://jsfiddle.net/h7evw1dq/1/

Comment: it's  an array data

Comment: @Vinoth I updated my answer, you don't need to send the whole array to parent but just only a new item to add.

Comment: @Vinoth Then you have to update **state** value `Data` in `addNewSeelctedItem` function. That will `rerender` your parent and child components and you can see the updated results.

Comment: Hi antonio: how to call the child method in parent component event. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817610/how-to-call-child-components-method-from-parent-components-event-in-reactjs

Comment: @Vinoth Haha. I have been trying to answer your question already.

Comment: HaHa Antonio, thanks for your response. I'm also trying in another side

Answer (score 2):

You can add a function to the parent component that will retrieve child components value.

Parent

```
  handleChildData = (value) => {
     do whatever you want to do with it
  }

 <IntegrationDownshift Members={this.state.Data} getData={this.handleChildData}/>
```

Child

```
<DownshiftMultiple classes={classes} Members={Members} childData={props.getData("test")}/>
```

Comment: Hi Emil, getData function is never called

Comment: @Emil 's is a good example. You can do it that way with both classes and hooks.

Comment: I should not get the childData as static value after did some operation in child component then the result should pass to parent.

Comment: here you can able to see my code in HTML section https://jsfiddle.net/h7evw1dq/1/

Comment: Instead of "test" you can add another function in child component and pass it in the getData argument, for example childData={props.getData(manageData())}/>, and in manageData you return value you want to.

Comment: Hi stever: how to call the child method in parent component event. stackoverflow.com/questions/56817610/…

Answer (score 1):

A prop can be a function, e.g. `onDataChanged`:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  ...
  setData(data) {
    console.log('setting data in App', data)
  }
  render() {
    ...
    <IntegrationDownshift ... onDataChanged={this.setData} />
    ...


export default function IntegrationDownshift(props) {
  ...
  props.onDataChanged("test")
}
```

That would call the `onDataChanged` prop in each render, which makes little sense, more likely it should be called only **inside an event handler** in the child.

Comment: I should not get the childData as static value after did some operation in child component then the result should pass to parent.

Comment: inside the operation in the child, you have to call `props.onDataChanged(result)` to pass it to parent

Comment: I have tried. I'm getting 'props.onDataChanged is not a function' this error

Comment: how many places in your code do you use `<IntegrationDownshift />`? in all of them, do you pass `onDataChanged` prop? correctly spelled?

Comment: here you can able to see my code in HTML section https://jsfiddle.net/h7evw1dq/1/

Comment: `IntegrationDownshift` is used 0 (zero) times in that fiddle, only exported, so I am unable to help with a problem undefined in the original question ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hi Aprillion: how to call the child method in parent component event. stackoverflow.com/questions/56817610/…

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a function in the parent that sets state, then pass that function to the child. Since it's bound to the parent you can run it in the child and the parent's state will be updated.

```
`import React from 'react';
    import IntegrationDownshift from './members'
    class App extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         Name: "Name from state...",
         Description: "Description from state...",
        Data:[data]
      }
    }
 *function getData(){
    this.setState({Name: 'this',
                   ....}) 
    }  *
   render() {  
     return (
        <div>
   <IntegrationDownshift Members={this.state.Data}/>
       </div>
     );
  }
 }

export default App;
```

Comment: can you give some reference link

Comment: I'm should not get the childData Value immediately after did some operation in child component then the result should pass to parent.